# W/DownloadManager( 7621): Aborting request for download 11:

Tags: android, ioexception, download-manager

```
E/UpdatesSettings( 7146): File write failed: java.io.IOException: open failed: EBUSY (Device or resource busy)
I/DownloadManager( 7621): Initiating request for download 11
W/DownloadManager( 7621): Aborting request for download 11: while opening destination file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/sysupdater/***.partial: open failed: EBUSY (Device or resource busy)
D/DownloadManager( 7621): cleanupDestination() deleting /storage/sdcard0/sysupdater/***.partial
```

I use `DownloadManager` to download file,sometimes it come out like this. Can anyone tell me why and how to solve this problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered a similar problem.

### To avoid FileNotFoundException, make sure you:

1. Add the required permissions to write to external storage (if that's where you're trying to save), add the following into the AndroidManifest.xml:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   ```
2. Create the subfolder you're attempting to download into:

   ```
   File folder = new File(FOLDER_PATH);
   if (!folder.exists()) {
       folder.mkdir();
   }
   ```